# Getting the size of the code segment of a DLL or EXE when loaded in memory

Tags: c++, winapi

I can use GetModuleHandle to get its base offset, but I also need to know the size of the code segment of the DLL or EXE. For example, I need to estimate nSize in this code:

```
char aCrashSignatureBytesAtEIP[] = { 0x87, 0x12, 0x00, ... };
char* pBaseOffset = (char*) GetModuleHandle(NULL);
int nSize = ???;
for (int i = 0; i<nSize; i++)
    if (!memcmp(&pBaseOffset[i], aCrashSignatureBytesAtEIP, sizeof(aCrashSignatureBytesAtEIP)))
    {
        printf("Crash signature found at offset %p", &pBaseOffset[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Just plain VirtualQuery will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PSAPI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you this: [`GetModuleInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function returns you [`MODULEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure with both base address and size of the image.

```
typedef struct _MODULEINFO {
  LPVOID lpBaseOfDll;
  DWORD  SizeOfImage;
  LPVOID EntryPoint;
} MODULEINFO, *LPMODULEINFO;
```